# How to update the selected checkbox using selected list with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular Material Checkbox. I have two different lists, one for a set of checkbox items and another one is for selected checkbox items. When the user switches the tabs I want to retain the state of the selected checkbox. But I unable to restore. Please help me

**Here is my HTML code**

```
<div *ngFor =" let alchoholwarningsign of alchoholwarningsigns">
    <mat-checkbox  checked="{{ existAlchoholSign(alchoholwarningsign) }}" 
    (click)="toggle(alchoholwarningsign, selectedalchoholwarningsigns)" 
   value="{{alchoholwarningsign}}">{{ alchoholwarningsign }}</mat-checkbox>                 
</div>
```

**Here is my TypeScript code:**

```
existAlchoholSign(alchohol){
  var idx = this.selectedalchoholwarningsigns.indexOf(alchohol);
  return idx > -1;
}
```

Comment: You should one-way binding instead of interpolation for the `checked` input.

Comment: Hi I tried one-way binding as well. But it did not work.